# How do I implement a fixed task pane in Outlook Web edition

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

How do I implement a fixed task pane in Outlook Web App?

Read the official documentation to see that the classic Outlook web App does not support a fixed task pane.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane

But I wonder how I can upgrade to Modern Outlook on the Web?

Our Server is installed with Exchange Server 2016 CU16

Comment: Are you using outlook.com? Can you please URL for outlook?

Comment: Although the pinnable task panes feature was introduced in requirement set 1.5, it's currently only available to Microsoft 365 subscribers.

Comment: I installed Exchange2016 locally and used OWA 2016